# writing to an Excel file with pandas/openpyxl returns an error or creates a file that needs to be repaired

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I run into an error with a script that worked perfectly up to 2 months ago.
I first copy a template Excel file with `shutil.copyfile`. So far so good.

I then create an ExcelWriter class with pandas:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_xl, engine="openpyxl")
# some extra stuff for filling the file, 
# not relevant since the issue shows up with these 3 lines already
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

This used to work without issue, but  I now receive this error:

`IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible`

Adding append mode:

`writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_xl, engine="openpyxl", mode="a")`

removes the error but when I open the Excel file, I get an error message saying the file needs to be repaired.

I use Python 3.7, pandas 1.2.3 and openpyxl 3.0.7.

Any idea what's going wrong?

**EDIT:**

Copy/Paste this code if you want to reproduce the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
from shutil import copyfile
template = r"path to any existing xlsx file"
out_xl = r"path to any xlsx file"
copyfile(template, out_xl)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_xl, engine="openpyxl", mode="a")
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: i voted back. for your patience.

Comment: `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_xl, engine="openpyxl")` will create a new "empty" Excel file overwriting the existing one.

Comment: The error message also acts as a catch-all error. With this in mind, check to see that there are no issues with any of the dataframes you are trying to write into a sheet. I noticed my dataframe itself returned an error. Once I debugged my dataframe, my excel file was able to be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following code to copy a Excel workbook, open it and write a small data frame to a new sheet

Instead of explicitly saving and closing the copied workbook I used a context manager.

The code runs without error and I can open the new workbook without any problems after the code has completed

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from shutil import copyfile

template = r"test.xlsx"
out_xl = r"out.xlsx"
copyfile(template, out_xl)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[5,6,7,9]})
with ExcelWriter(out_xl, mode="a", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet3")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I added 2 lines to import the workbook (`writer.book = load_workbook(out_xl`)and sheets (`writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)`), otherwise the data frame gets copied to a new sheet.

Comment: can you explain why OP got error `At least one sheet must be visible` and try to fix that code? i think your code is just walkaround. if not to reproduce that issue, even no need  use `ExcelWriter` if you can use `df.to_excel` directly?

Comment: It's not really a workaround, using a context manager is good practice - if I was writing this sort of code I would probably start with it. As for explaining why they got the error, I might be able to but I couldn't reproduce the error using the original code.

Comment: i can reproduce the issue just by copying that last code snippet(of course change the file paths to some actual ones)